# innerHTML shows text but not HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, innerhtml

I am trying to write a simple table using a JSON data source and javascript. I have the data and loop working, but when the HTML is written at the end of the function only the text is placed into the DOM, and not the tags I wrapped the text in. In my [example shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/lyonsinbeta/erqDe/), I included a console.log so you can see the DOM does not include the `<tr>` and `</tr>` but the variable does because it is printed in the console.

I suspect this is an issue with the `innerHTML` method but I haven't been able to figure out the difference between my example and some working examples I've found.

**Update to include code example:**

```
<table>
    <td id="web">
    </td>
</table>

<script>
var cv = {
  "webinars": [
    { "title": "Zombies Ate My Neighborhood" },
    { "title": "Pacman Fever" },
    { "title": "Googleplex" }
  ]
};

function writeTable() { 
    var table = "";
    cv.webinars.forEach (function(item) {
        table += "<tr>" + item.title + "</tr>" + "\n";
    });
    console.log(table);
    node = document.getElementById("web");
    node.innerHTML = table;
}

writeTable();
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bbuecherl/erqDe/1/

Comment: Why is your example posted on a different website, and not here? Voting to close since there's not enough information directly in the question suitable to determine the issue.

Comment: My question is posted on a different website because I referenced the viewed behavior as well as the console behavior. I didn't realize that was negative behavior though. I'll update my question to include more detail. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Thanks to attila, oriol and laukik-patel I was able to get what I needed. I can't @ tag you, but upvotes for each! [Here is the fixed jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/lyonsinbeta/erqDe/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. One, TDs go inside of TRs. Two, you cannot set the innerHTML of a TR since it is read only in IE. In order to do what you want in a cross-browser compatible way, either build the whole table in a string and set the innerHTML of a container, like a DIV. Or, you can create the table elements and append them to the DOM.

Comment: It is definitely not cross browser compatible. Here is a link from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: IE doesn't know how to work with tables... The [spec](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#innerhtml) doesn't say `innerHTML` is read-only for tabular elements.

Comment: I updated my answer to specify IE. I guess there are two different schools when it comes to developing for web browsers - either you just follow the HTML DOM specs and tell everyone using a browser that doesn't 100% support the specs "too bad", or you try your best to build it in a cross-browser compatible way so everyone can enjoy your work.

Answer (score 2):

You used `<tr>` instead of `<td>` and viceversa. `<td>` is a cell and must go in a `<tr>` (table row).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/erqDe/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<table>
  <tbody id="web">
  </tbody>
</table>


<script>
var cv = {
  "webinars": [
    { "title": "Zombies Ate My Neighborhood" },
    { "title": "Pacman Fever" },
    { "title": "Googleplex" }
  ]
};

function writeTable() { 
    var table = "";
    cv.webinars.forEach (function(item) {
        table += "<tr>" + item.title + "</tr>" + "\n";
    });
    console.log(table);
    node = document.getElementById("web");
    node.innerHTML = table;
}

writeTable();
</script>
```